# VB.NET Sort WrapPanel by Children Data

Tags: vb.net, sorting, wrappanel

I have a project where i generate data and number it (1 - 500) by using many threads and place it inside a Label which i then place inside a grid which i then place inside a WrapPanel.

The Problem. 
Some of the data in threads finish before others. So my Wrap panel gets the numbers like 
3 1 5 6 10 2 4 7 8 9. I want to sort the warp panel after all the threads have finished so they look like 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

```
Private Sub StartSearch_MouseLeftButtonUp
    Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf SearchBegin)
    t.Start(Data)
End Sub

Sub SearchBegin(Data)
    Dim Max = 10
    Dim Count = 1
    While Count < Max
        Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf Check)
        t.Start(Data)
        count += 1
    End While
End Sub

Sub Check(Data)
    'things happen here
    Dim display As New Action(Of Object)(AddressOf Progress)
    WrapPanel1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(display, Data)
End Sub

Sub Progress(Data)
    Dim g As New Grid
    'Pretty Up Grid
    Dim l As New Label
    'Pretty Up Label
    l.Content = Data.tostring
    g.Children.Add(l)
    WrapPanel1.Children.Add(g)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Barrier.

**To wait for all threads to be completed,** define a global barrier:

```
Dim barr As New Threading.Barrier(1)
```

Add participant before starting threads:

```
Sub startathread()
    barr.AddParticipant()
    Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf blabla)
    t.Start()
End Sub
```

As the job is done, signal that it is done:

```
 Sub blabla()
    'do stuff
    barr.SignalAndWait()
 End Sub
```

Now the function starting all threads and waiting for all to be completed:

```
Sub x()
    For i = 0 To 9
        startathread()
    Next
    barr.SignalAndWait()
    'from this line on, all the threads are completed their jobs.
End Sub
```

**For sorting,** your thread must add each data to a list:

```
Dim datalist As New List(Of String)

Sub Progress(Data)
    datalist.Add(Data.ToString)
End Sub
```

When addition of all data is done a function to sort and place them must be called:

```
Sub SortAndPlace()
    datalist.Sort()

    For Each sdata In datalist
        Dim g As New Grid
        'Pretty Up Grid
        Dim l As New Label
        'Pretty Up Label
        l.Content = sdata
        g.Children.Add(l)
        WrapPanel1.Children.Add(g)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I noticed this Threading.Barrier is for Framework 4.5 and does not work with 3.5. I also was trying to display the data as soon as i could. But this answer does work so ill mark it as correct. Thank you alot for your help

Comment: 4.0 also supports. Btw, since you want them to be sorted, and the outcome can not be determined before all the task is completed, there is no other way but waiting for all, I think.